# Parameters in URL using Angular's UI-Router, issue with .otherwise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I want to search on my page. Actually, my code is

```
$stateProvider
  .state('aaa', {
    url: '/aaa',
    templateUrl: 'client/parties/views/aaa.ng.html',
    controller: 'Aaa'
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/default");
```

And now, I want to search on my page, but the params MUST working with the URL.
How to use params when I have $urlRouterProvider.otherwise?
Actually, everything after /aaa/ in URL causes redirect to /default.

Important thing: I have more than 20 parameters, but when there're not selected, I don't want to pass it via URL. This is important because I think I can't do something like url: '/details/:param1:param2:param3:param4',

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) for ui-router, it doesn't seem like it is possible to not have it redirect without having at least one parameter defined on the state's route.

To accomplish what you want, I think the best is to use a catch all parameter of some sort. It's either that, restricting deep-linking, or reducing the amount of parameters and manually defining it.

1. Define a catch all parameter as shown below. In this case the parameter is path redirects will not take place if there is nothing after "/files/":

   > '**/files/{path:.*}'** - Matches any URL starting with '/files/' and captures the rest of the path into the parameter 'path'.
   >   **'/files/*path'** - Ditto. Special syntax for catch all.
2. Define one parameter on a new route, and then split the one parameter into multiple parameters in the controller.

Comment: I'm trying now with passing all the parameters in one parameter in .state, but I have an issue.

When I want to go to my state: 

$state.transitionTo('partiesWithParams', {searchParams:'lol'}, { reload: false, inherit: false, notify: true }); 

whole the page is reloading. How to prevent it?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1758 or https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2087